# Detect class of an object conforming to a protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a series of classes that conform to a specific protocol. For example:

```
@protocol Consumable
@end
```

And one of several classes:

```
@interface LivingEntity : Entity<Consumable>
...
```

In other parts of the app, I check if the object `conformsToProtocol`, and I cast them using:

```
id<Consumable> consumable = (id<Consumable>) something;
```

The problem is that `consumable` is then handed off to several methods. One of them needs additional logic if the `consumable` is an instance of the `LivingEntity` class.

However, there's no way to check if `[consumable class] == [LivingEntity class]`.

How can I check which class it is? Seems like the protocol cast prevents me from using `NSObject` methods.

Comment: Why is there no way to check? You can send any message you want to an `id`.

Comment: xcode shows an error, `No known instance method for selector 'class'`

Comment: The problem is that the protocol should "inherit" from the `NSObject` protocol (yes, there's such a thing), like `@protocol P <NSObject>`. That angle bracket part is probably what's missing. While I'm at it, you should look at Carl's answer for how to check class membership. `==` might work for now, but it's not the accepted way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming all classes conforming to `Consumable` would also conform to the `NSObject` protocol, generally meaning they all descend from either `NSObject` or `NSProxy`, have `Consumable` extend `NSObject`, allowing you to use the `-isKindOfClass:` and `-isMemberOfClass:` methods:

```
@protocol Consumable <NSObject>
...
@end
```

Then you would check using `isKindOfClass:` if you wanted to check for `LivingEntity` or any of its subclasses, or `isMemberOfClass:` if you needed to check only for `LivingEntity`, excluding its subclasses. For example:

```
if([consumable isKindOfClass:[LivingEntity class]]) {...}
```

Comment: While @carl's answer should work for you.  You should really reconsider the protocol definition if the caller is still trying to make decisions based on the class of the callee.  Perhaps add a new method to the protocol `-(bool)needsExtraHandling`?  Although hopefully you'd name it more appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [ClassName conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ProtocolName)] to check if an object conforms to a particular protocol or not.